# Talking NPC-s with commands post 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been developing an adventure map in 1.12.2 for quite some time, and decided to upgrade to 1.13+.
I created NPC-s who talk when the player approaches them. It works this way:

- `/execute @e[tag=talking_npc] ~ ~ ~ testfor @p[r=2]` <- in a repeat, always active command block.
- A redstone comparator
- `/execute @e[tag=talking_npc] ~ ~ ~ say "Something"` <- in a regual, redstone activated command block

This way when the first command block finds a player, it sends a redstone signal to the comparator, which in turn activates the second command block. This way the npc executes the SAY command only once.
[image: picture of command block system]

My question is that now from 1.13 the testfor command has been removed, I've been trying to create this system with execute command and failed so far. When I approach the npc, the command executes repeatedly, which is obviously not correct. Is there any way to make it post 1.13?

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The /execute command received some new features in 1.13, such as conditional statements ("if" and "unless") which can be used as an equivalent for /testfor. here is the 1.13 version of your commands:

```
/execute at @e[tag=talking_npc] if entity @a[distance=..2]

/execute as @e[tag=talking_npc] run say "Something"
```

Comment: This is actually not the problem that the asker has, the question is just confusingly worded. Their problem is executing it only once.

Comment: I indeed worded the question confusingly, but his answer was what I was looking for! Thanks for the help! :)